# the area of an irregular cyclic polygon from given corner point angles!!!!

Tags: geometry

how can I calculate the area of an irregular cyclic polygon from given corner point angles ?
 I have a corner point angles given to me in the question.
Also, What i need is a formula for finding an area of an irregular cyclic polygon by using corner point angles.

in order to do my c++ homework, I have to solve this first.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrvzc.png)

Comment: Please add the relevant information to the question itself instead of links to screenshots. Don't forget to add your thoughts and attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: i added a picture to explain my question more.

Comment: [You have already asked this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1494853/409)

Comment: In addition, I have that question answered.

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate the area triangle by triange. 
Using the Heron formula, we have, for each triangle $OAB$
$A=\sqrt{s(s-OA)(s-OB)(s-AB)},\quad s=\frac{OA+OB+OC}{2}$

With $OA=OB=1$, we have $s=\frac{AB}{2}+1$

$A=\sqrt{s(s-OA)(s-OB)(s-AB)}=\sqrt{(\frac{AB}{2}+1)(\frac{AB}{2})(\frac{AB}{2})(1-\frac{AB}{2})}=\frac{1}{4}AB \sqrt{4-AB^2}$

Now you just have to find the formula to have $AB$